# How do I register routing listening in rxjs6 and change the title?

Tags: angular, router, rxjs6

- in `rxjs5`(angular6 app), I use

  ```
  this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map(route => {
      while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
      }
      return route;`enter code here`
    })
    .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
    .mergeMap(route => route.data)
    .subscribe((event) => {
      this.titleService.setTitle(event['title'] + '-' + APP_NAME);
      this.appDataLogic.urlChanged();
  });
  ```
- But in `rxjs6`, `route` is `{}` so that has error `property firstChild does not exist on type {}`.

  ```
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => { return this.activatedRoute }).pipe(),
    map(route => {
      while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
      }
      return route;
   }),
   filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
   mergeMap(route => route.data)
   ).subscribe((event) => {
   this.titleService.setTitle(event['title'] + '-');
  })
  ```
- How do I rewrite it with rxjs6? thanks a lot.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)  you should still be able to use .firstChild

Comment: Why is it `.pipe(),` here?

Comment: @yurzui, he's using Angular 6 for the second eg and since Rxjs6 you can't chain `map` directly to an `Observable`. It needs to be inside a `pipe` call.

Comment: @SiddAjmera  I know that, i'm talking about this line `map(() => { return this.activatedRoute }).pipe(),`

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that. Yeah, it's redundant.

Comment: `map(() => { return this.activatedRoute }).pipe()` This nuked it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I found a solution it is :

````
```
 this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
          route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return route;
      }),
      filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap(route => route.data)
    ).subscribe((event) => {
      //some code
    })
```
````

But i have a another question, it is used in `ngOnInit()` in `app.component.ts`, `app.component.ts` is my root component, should i unsubscribe it in `ngOnDestroy()`?

Comment: Since you will never destroy your AppComponent then you can leave it as it is. But it is encouraged to always remembering about your subscriptions

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will do that.